# Running Maven project on Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, deployment, configuration

I have a Maven Project in Eclipse. I want to deploy it in my local tomcat server and run it like normal J2EE projects.

But What i found is in tomcat add/remove projects option, no project is shown.
Right click on maven project and run as doesn't have Run on Server option or may be I am missing something.

All I am looking for running Maven projects (from eclipse, no command prompt or manual copy paste of wars) in local Tomcat server just like normal J2EE projects without modifying pom.xml (seriously I don't want to modify this)

Comment: Are you using m2eclipse?

Comment: Yes. the only way to use maven in eclipse is m2e ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Eclipse `Maven Integration for WTP` must be installed. Also this project must be configured with web nature.

**UPDATE**

To turn on web nature in your project properties -> Project Facets -> Convert to faceted form... -> Dynamic Web Module -> OK

Comment: @NitinGurram Good. Then you must enable project dynamic web module  facet. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To complete [AleksandrM  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12895909/428236), if someone wants to make their *existing* eclipse web project maven aware in Eclipse,  highlight the project in explorer -> Right mouse click and select **Configure** -> **Convert To Maven Project**

Answer (score 1):

There can be a few reasons why you don't see the project in the Add/Remove projects dialog for Tomcat.  Verify the following:

1. You have `m2e` installed (http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/)
2. You have `m2e-wtp` installed (http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/download/)
3. Your Maven project imported as a `Dynamic Web Application`.  Look for a `Deployment Descriptor` entry when you expand the project, it should be somewhere in the first few entries.  It is the second one down for me on Eclipse Juno.  Not there?  It's probably not a web app.  Go back and verify 1 & 2, then remove and re-import your project.
4. Make sure that your web application is not too new for the version of Tomcat that you are using.  Right-click the project and go to `Properties` > `Project Facets`.  Look for `Dynamic Web Module` and check the version.  If this version is too new for your Tomcat version, Eclipse won't let you add it.  For instance, your `Dynamic Web Module` version is 3.0 and you're using Tomcat 6.