# How to run wicket examples?

Tags: java, dynamic, web, project, wicket

I am new to web prog. and wicket, so i went to below site to run example source codes to play with applications.

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/index.html

Simply i create a "dynamic web project" and try to copy source codes to project.

All example's application classes are that type,

```
   public class ...(ex.name).Application extends WicketExampleApplication
```

On the internet i found some of those examples with classes WebApplication, and i managed to run those examples, like that

```
   public class ...(ex.name).Application extends WebApplication
```

So my question are;

1-How can i simply run those examples using dynamic web projects?

2-Copying source codes to my project after that how can i call libraries in my project using maven?

I searched many questions but couldnt find any topic who is trying to run those examples simply in a project.

Thanks.

Soso

Comment: what error does it show to you? is it a compile or runtime error?

Comment: Mr fmodos, my problem is I dont know how to run http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/linkomatic/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?1&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.linkomatic.Home example with tomcat. I want to open a project wicket quickstart maybe and copy the source but there are many jars confıguratıons whıch is complex for me, so want use maven effectively to run each examples alone. Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, you can use maven to configure a wicket project. Follow the tutorial: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/windows-guide-to-installing-wicket-on-eclipse-with-maven.html after you have it configure you just need to change the applicationClassName property in the web.xml indicating which application you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

1. instead of doing all the messy work just run mvn using tthis 
   [http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html]
2. now just copy the sources

if you any problem and you want to add wicket to an existing project just copy the web..xml , wicket jars and you would have wicket project (i would recomend wicket from another opm connecting you existing services and this way decouple services from the web container ...)

P. S the WebApplication thing they just inehrited it and called ExampleWebApplication

Comment: 1-Using link http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html , i created a poject and import it to eclipse. 2- "Run on server" doent shown so i applied this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895734/running-maven-project-on-tomcat-from-eclipse

Comment: 3- It didnt work and Console is like that: INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin; ....WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:mymaven' did not find a matching property.
Nis 07, 2013 1:39:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init ...    You say "2.now just copy the sources" for example i want to run linkomatic project, it has sources, should just import sources?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to use maven integration

1. Install Eclipse (that support Java EE)
2. Add all required maven related plugins

   - Version Control: Use Subclipse 1.8.x, see: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x
   - Maven Integration: m2e , is included in Eclipse Classic. Use
     Help->Install New Software, select "--All available sites--" and
     choose Collaboration -> m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse
   - Subclipse/Maven Integration: Update site: http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/1.0/

Then, just checkout the maven examples you got on the web

Go Eclipse--Window-->Show view-->Other

Type svn and select SVN repositories and open it

Then copy the check out address and add it to the svn repositories View

finaly, right click on the link you have added and check out as maven projects.

If you want to create new Maven projects

Create new maven Projects, new-->project-->Maven project

then in new Maven Project Window, in the Filer Text box, Type wicket and select **org.apche.wicket as a groupID**
After that, you can have your maven codes working well.

If still you got some debug errors, you can open your **pom.xml** file and add dependencies such as **wicket-core** and **wicket-extensions**

Comment: Mr Times, First thanks for your detailed response. I believe the topic will be so handful for many beginners to wicket like me on the net. 1. and 2. is Ok. I stuck after svn part. This is the link of one of wicket projects and "source code" link is there. http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/echo/?0  You say "just checkout the maven examples you got on the web". Should I just copy the url link to svn? Or copy source to a file like Desktop-> SvnMy-> Echo-> Echo.java, Echo.html, EchoApplication.java and give this link to svn? Sorry I couldnt understand that.Can you pls be more specific.