# Eclipse-Kepler, Maven and Setup Tomcat 7 debug (hot deploy)

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have maven based project with following structure:

1. main_project

   - module_webproject
   - module_java_proj_1
   - module_java_proj_2
   - module_java_proj_3
   - ... ...

Everything compiles and packages fine with command line maven goals execution. I need to setup this project into eclipse environment for developers with tomcat deployment. Anyone know setup instructions?

Also, i am looking into tomcat hot deploy for debugging capabilities.

I have tried mvn eclipse:eclipse, this does only creation of .project and .classpath files. But projects directories are not treated as java or web projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from following forum some what helps...
[[Running Maven project on Tomcat from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895734/running-maven-project-on-tomcat-from-eclipse])

There can be a few reasons why you don't see the project in the Add/Remove projects dialog for Tomcat.  Verify the following:

1. You have `m2e` installed (http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/)
2. You have `m2e-wtp` installed (http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/download/)
3. Your Maven project imported as a `Dynamic Web Application`.  Look for a `Deployment Descriptor` entry when you expand the project, it should be somewhere in the first few entries.  It is the second one down for me on Eclipse Juno.  Not there?  It's probably not a web app.  Go back and verify 1 & 2, then remove and re-import your project.
4. Make sure that your web application is not too new for the version of Tomcat that you are using.  Right-click the project and go to `Properties` > `Project Facets`.  Look for `Dynamic Web Module` and check the version.  If this version is too new for your Tomcat version, Eclipse won't let you add it.  For instance, your `Dynamic Web Module` version is 3.0 and you're using Tomcat 6.