# Spring Roo can't run with shortcut `Run as Server`

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo

I have this SpringRoo repository I have just cloned and imported on my Eclipse workspace. The Eclipse I'm using now is a newly download Eclipse Standard 4.3.2. I have installed the WTP (3.5.2) and SpringSource (all of them) plugins. Also I have installed a new Apache Tomcat 7 on my terminal.

The problem is that after importing the SpringRoo project (via Maven) on the workspace and resolved some issues with `pom.xml`, I can't get to run the application because I can't see `Run As Server` option on the `Run As` menu. How could I get the project/eclipse to have this feature again?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12895734/1700321.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo doesn't run in a server ... you should read the reference guide and understand what is Roo.

Any way, you can "Run As ..." the applications you create with Roo, not Roo itself.