# Manage Tomcat with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I used to manually manage my Tomcat server but I am currently installing Tomcat as a professionnal user now and I prefer that my Eclipse IDE totally manage my Tomcat installation to be sure to have a clean project management.

I looked up for some tutorials on the web and I found I have to install the Eclipe for Java EE then go to the Server tab at the bottom, click New, choose my tomcat version (8.5 for me), then click Next.
Here I have to locate my Tomcat installation so I did it.
Finally I tried to create a new project but it seems to not working well.

Basically what I want it does is when I click on "Create new Java web project" it create it on my Tomcat webapps directory and automatically generate the web.xml, the class folder and even the index.jsp if it's possible. Then I should be able to create a new XXX.jsp directly in Eclipse to get it working in tomcat (and accessible by taping http://localhost:8080/projectName/XXX.jsp in my browser)

Is it possible ? How can I setting up my Eclipse to get it working ?

Comment: My experience with application server management from eclipse is: eclipse has no good support for servers. But maybe I am just missing the right configuration window or plugin.

Comment: check this for running tomcat from eclipse [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895734/running-maven-project-on-tomcat-from-eclipse)

Comment: To Korashen : I would like to use the IntelliJ IDEA IDE but only the pro version is handling the web development and we have to pay it.
To : Joyson I haven't any project for the moment, I only have mt tomcat working and my eclipse too and I want that when I create a new Eclipse project it create it into tomcat folder with all the necessary files to run a tomcat servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after thousands of google researches I finally found a tutorial which explains how can I get something near that I want :

http://salmanawan.com/hello-world-jsp-tutorial-using-eclipse-ide/

Sure it's not as simple as I expected but with this I could get a clean project management fully generated by Eclipse.

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if plugin/different eclipse version support this. But yes you can definitely create your own plugin with required functionality and then create new web project using your plugin instead of using eclipse provided new web project feature.

Comment: I was preferably looking for a plugin already created but well... Thanks anyway !